# How to choose number of bins in numpy.histogram?

Tags: python, numpy, numbers, histogram, bins

If I use histogram of matplotlib , I can choose the number of bins.
But how can I choose the number of bins at histogram of numpy?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
array = [1,3,4,4,8,9,10,12]

range = int((max(array)) - min(array))+1
x, bins, patch = plt.hist(array, bins=range)
```

In this case range = number of bins = (12-1)+1 = 12

So the result is 
x = [ 1.  0.  1.  2.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  1.]

But the result of numpy is

```
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(array, density=False)
```

numpy = [1 1 2 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
numpy_bin = [  1.    2.1   3.2   4.3   5.4   6.5   7.6   8.7   9.8  10.9  12. ]

When using numpy , how can I choose the number of bins(= int((max(array)) - min(array))+1)

I want the same result like matplotlib

Comment: Use `bincount` : `np.bincount(array)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matplotlib is using numpys histogram, to pass number of bins simply add `bins=bin_range` as keyword argument to `np.histogram`:

```
hist, edges = np.histogram(array, bins=bin_range, density=False)
```

If `bin_range` is an integer number you get `bin_range` amount of equal sized bins. The default value for bins in `np.histogram` is `bins='auto'` which uses an algorithm to decide the number of bins. Read more at: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html

```
array = [1,3,4,4,8,9,10,12]
bin_range = int((max(array)) - min(array))+1
x, bins, patch = plt.hist(array, bins=bin_range)

x
array([ 1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.])

hist, edges = np.histogram(array, bins=bin_range)

hist
array([1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], dtype=int64)

bins == edges
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: `range` is a default Python function. Using it as a variable is going to cause problems, so I'd strongly suggest calling it something else.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and for pointing this out. This was so long ago that it seems like a silly mistake even when trying to explain something. It seems I was also trying to use the same variables